# How to speed up query execution in a table that has more than 100 000 000 rows and has a WHERE and ORDER (order by timestamp) clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a problem related to SQL query optimization. I'm working in a PostgreSQL database, but I **assume it's more or less the same for all databases**.

The problem is this:

I have a table with more than 100 000 000 rows and I need to select only the first 20/25 rows that match the condition in the WHERE clause. Additionally, the rows must be the most recently added to the table. The query is simple:

```
SELECT * 
FROM transactions
WHERE transactions.from = '0xfbde4acae6c489197280635f0fa172148c61838b'
   OR transactions.to = '0xfbde4acae6c489197280635f0fa172148c61838b'
ORDER BY transactions.timestamp DESC 
LIMIT 25;
```

EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFER) for the above query:

```
"QUERY PLAN"
"Limit  (cost=2174753.21..2174756.12 rows=25 width=324) (actual time=5225.725..5242.938 rows=25 loops=1)"
"  Output: hash, block_hash, block_number, ""from"", ""to"", gas, gas_used, gas_price, nonce, transaction_index, value, contract_address, status, ""timestamp"""
"  Buffers: shared hit=17 read=146499 dirtied=6 written=379"
"  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=2174753.21..2214827.74 rows=343472 width=324) (actual time=5225.723..5242.935 rows=25 loops=1)"
"        Output: hash, block_hash, block_number, ""from"", ""to"", gas, gas_used, gas_price, nonce, transaction_index, value, contract_address, status, ""timestamp"""
"        Workers Planned: 2"
"        Workers Launched: 2"
"        Buffers: shared hit=17 read=146499 dirtied=6 written=379"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=2173753.18..2174182.52 rows=171736 width=324) (actual time=5212.330..5212.332 rows=19 loops=3)"
"              Output: hash, block_hash, block_number, ""from"", ""to"", gas, gas_used, gas_price, nonce, transaction_index, value, contract_address, status, ""timestamp"""
"              Sort Key: transactions.""timestamp"" DESC"
"              Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 40kB"
"              Buffers: shared hit=17 read=146499 dirtied=6 written=379"
"              Worker 0:  actual time=5205.779..5205.781 rows=25 loops=1"
"                Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 39kB"
"                Buffers: shared hit=5 read=49090 dirtied=2 written=117"
"              Worker 1:  actual time=5205.776..5205.778 rows=25 loops=1"
"                Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 42kB"
"                Buffers: shared hit=7 read=49181 dirtied=2 written=134"
"              ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on public.transactions  (cost=6130.59..2168906.92 rows=171736 width=324) (actual time=33.562..5167.871 rows=131846 loops=3)"
"                    Output: hash, block_hash, block_number, ""from"", ""to"", gas, gas_used, gas_price, nonce, transaction_index, value, contract_address, status, ""timestamp"""
"                    Recheck Cond: ((transactions.""from"" = '0xfbde4acae6c489197280635f0fa172148c61838b'::bpchar) OR (transactions.""to"" = '0xfbde4acae6c489197280635f0fa172148c61838b'::bpchar))"
"                    Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 663904"
"                    Heap Blocks: exact=13510 lossy=33729"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=5 read=146497 dirtied=6 written=379"
"                    Worker 0:  actual time=26.980..5162.413 rows=133634 loops=1"
"                      Buffers: shared read=49088 dirtied=2 written=117"
"                    Worker 1:  actual time=27.062..5162.932 rows=132710 loops=1"
"                      Buffers: shared read=49181 dirtied=2 written=134"
"                    ->  BitmapOr  (cost=6130.59..6130.59 rows=412182 width=0) (actual time=40.743..40.744 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=5 read=349"
"                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on from_idx  (cost=0.00..5840.70 rows=406417 width=0) (actual time=40.487..40.487 rows=401210 loops=1)"
"                                Index Cond: (transactions.""from"" = '0xfbde4acae6c489197280635f0fa172148c61838b'::bpchar)"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=3 read=347"
"                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on to_idx  (cost=0.00..83.81 rows=5765 width=0) (actual time=0.254..0.254 rows=124 loops=1)"
"                                Index Cond: (transactions.""to"" = '0xfbde4acae6c489197280635f0fa172148c61838b'::bpchar)"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=2 read=2"
"Planning Time: 0.108 ms"
"Execution Time: 5243.004 ms"
```

The problem is that this query takes so long to execute (4+ seconds; sometimes it takes more than 8 seconds). Of course, the reason is the order of execution of the commands (FROM -> WHERE -> SELECT -> ORDERS BY -> LIMIT).

So it's going through all 100 000 000 rows, then select the rows that match the WHERE clause, then ORDER them and finally take the first 25 rows.

**It is important to note that I have indexes over the transactions.from and transactions.to columns**

I am also doing a following query to see how many rows match the WHERE clause in total:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM transactions
WHERE transactions.from = '0xfbde4acae6c489197280635f0fa172148c61838b' 
   OR transactions.to = '0xfbde4acae6c489197280635f0fa172148c61838b'
```

The strange thing is that when the second query gives some small number the first query executes fast (up to 300 milliseconds). Otherwise, when it gives big count number, the first query has the low execution speed. So, I guess the ORDER is the problem, because if the WHERE clause gives back, for example, 200 000 matches, it must order it and that takes some time. So, my question is: **Is there a way to optimize this? Using a non-cluster index for the timestamp would not make sense to me (or maybe it would?). Has anyone had a similar problem and does anyone know how to speed up query execution?**

Comment: Please edit the question to include the table schema, relevant indexes and query [EXPLAIN ANALYZE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html) output. You may find limiting the rows the db has to look at (by adding `where timestamp > *dont-care-about-data-before-this-ts*`) is the quickest path to an improvement.

Comment: @AD7six `where timestamp > *dont-care-about-data-before-this-ts` This doesn't help me. I need the first 25 rows regardless of whether the timestamp of the row is 1 day or 1 year.

Comment: Could you please share the results (in plain text) from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) for this statement and the DDL for you table, including the indexes? Otherwise we have nothing to work on.

Comment: @AD7six Yes, of course, I am working on it

Comment: @AD7six Done. I hope you have everything you need now. Unfortunately, I am not able to provide a table scheme, but none of the columns used are part of the primary key.

Comment: @FrankHeikens Done. I shared everything I could. If you also need the `EXPLAIN` of the second query, I can share it too.

Comment: The explain output as a quote is hard to read - please format it as a code block and maintain the whitespace (that isn't present, so I can't do this for you). Also, not sure what `It is important to note that I have indexes over the transactions.from and transactions.to columns` means - but please don't do that - just show the index definitions e.g. via `\d table_name` with psql.

Comment: @AD7six I formatted as you asked. I hope it's ok now. About indexes: I know, but I can't give any information (more than this) related to the structure of the database. I hope you have everything you need now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL is rather weak in this regard.  I don't know if other DBMS are better, but it is at least questionable to assume they are all the same.  You can get good performance, but it requires you to do the heavy lifting yourself, by writing the query in a rather contorted way:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)
(select * from transactions WHERE transactions.from = 871 order by timestamp desc limit 25) 
union all 
(select * from transactions where transactions.to = 871 order by timestamp desc limit 25) 
ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 25;
```

This will give you fast plan as long as you have two two-column indexes, on `("from", timestamp)` and `("to", timestamp)`.  It will read the tuples already ordered using each index then merge them with a Merge Append.  Note that if a row qualifies on both the "from" and the "to", then that row will be returned two times, so this query is not formally identical to your current one.

Note that the 2 "inner" ORDER BY and LIMIT specifications are not necessary to get the correct answer, but they are necessary to get the fast plan.  Otherwise it resorts to a slow plan similar to the one you already have.

This is the fast plan:

```
 Limit  (cost=0.88..101.07 rows=25 width=16) (actual time=15.738..62.608 rows=25 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=10 read=22
   I/O Timings: shared/local read=61.744
   ->  Merge Append  (cost=0.88..201.26 rows=50 width=16) (actual time=15.734..62.579 rows=25 loops=1)
         Sort Key: transactions."timestamp" DESC
         Buffers: shared hit=10 read=22
         I/O Timings: shared/local read=61.744
         ->  Limit  (cost=0.43..100.37 rows=25 width=16) (actual time=14.636..50.620 rows=16 loops=1)
               Buffers: shared hit=4 read=15
               I/O Timings: shared/local read=50.054
               ->  Index Scan Backward using transactions_from_timestamp_idx on transactions  (cost=0.43..4009.98 rows=1003 width=16) (actual time=14.634..50.589 rows=16 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ("from" = 19)
                     Buffers: shared hit=4 read=15
                     I/O Timings: shared/local read=50.054
         ->  Limit  (cost=0.43..100.37 rows=25 width=16) (actual time=1.092..11.910 rows=10 loops=1)
               Buffers: shared hit=6 read=7
               I/O Timings: shared/local read=11.690
               ->  Index Scan Backward using transactions_to_timestamp_idx on transactions transactions_1  (cost=0.43..3997.92 rows=1000 width=16) (actual time=1.089..11.900 rows=10 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ("to" = 19)
                     Buffers: shared hit=6 read=7
                     I/O Timings: shared/local read=11.690
 Planning Time: 0.898 ms
 Execution Time: 62.808 ms
```

For demo purposes I converted the column types to int, for ease of random data generation.  But that should have no meaningful effect on the performance.

> So, I guess the ORDER is the problem, because if the WHERE clause gives back, for example, 200 000 matches, it must order it and that takes some time

If you look at your original plan, the Sort only takes a trivial amount of time, less than 1% of the total time: (5212.332-5167.871) / 5242.938.  The ORDER is the problem only indirectly, because, as a precursor to sorting 131846 rows, you first need to read 131846 rows scattered randomly across your table, and that takes a lot of random IO, which is slow.  By reading them already in order and preserving that order with Merge Append, the fast plan gets to stop early once it reaches the LIMIT.